# How do I add order & orderby parameters to this wordpress query?

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-order-by

I managed to paint myself into a corner when using this snippet, but I can't manage to work out how to sort the query. Usually I can do it but with this snippet that excludes one tag on the tag page I can't really work it out. Anyone?

```
$exclude_tags = array(17);

global $wp_query;
$wp_query->set('tag__not_in', $exclude_tags);

$wp_query->get_posts();

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Answer (score 0):

This example will be help full for you :-

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'meta_key' => 'pb_issue_featured',
        'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => $posts,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'paged' => 1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'headline',
                'value' => 1,
                'compare' => '!=' 
                )
            )
        );

add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'filter_query' );
$q = new WP_Query($args);
remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'filter_query' );

function filter_query( $query ) {
    $query .= ', wp_posts.menu_order ASC';
    return $query;
}
```

[Referenced From](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109849/order-by-desc-asc-in-custom-wp-query)

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this example. You can do like this.

The code will display the title of last ten posts sorted alphabetically in ascending order.

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title' );
    $postslist = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $postslist as $post ) :
      setup_postdata( $post ); ?> 
        <div>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php
    endforeach; 
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Please refer the link http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts for more details.